# Spring Transactional without rollback

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-transactions

```
 @Transactional
 public void setSomething(String name) { ... }
```

Sorry to ask this very basic question, Spring `@Transactional` annotation is so powerful but yet super hard to understand.

Based on the code above, I don't have `rollbackFor` control, meaning, if there is exception, this *transactional* context will not be rollback. But based on my experience in old way to covering transaction block, if there is no rollback for exception, `commit` will be skipped and cause the (Oracle) database's table being locked (suspend, other user can't commit their SQL).

Will Spring have the same issue without using `rollbackFor`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `rollbackFor` and related parameters are for fine-tuning. If you omit them, the default behaviour is to rollback for `RuntimeExceptions`. Other exceptions don't perform a rollback and any changes made into the database will be committed.

The transaction is either committed or rolled back, there's no way a `@Transactional` method will result in an unterminated transaction (at least in normal operation).

Answer (score 9):

The default `<tx:advice/>` / `@Transactional` settings are:

- Propagation setting is `REQUIRED`.
- Isolation level is `DEFAULT`.
- Transaction is read/write.
- Transaction timeout defaults to the default timeout of the underlying
- Transaction system, or none if timeouts are not supported.
- **Any `RuntimeException` triggers *rollback*, and any checked Exception does not.**

So in your case this will be rollbacked if you will have a `RuntimeException`.

But usually it is not sufficient to tell you simply to annotate your classes with the `@Transactional` annotation, add `@EnableTransactionManagement` to your configuration.

You can configure exactly which Exception types mark a transaction for rollback, including *checked exceptions*. The following XML snippet demonstrates how you configure rollback for a *checked*, application-specific Exception type.

```xml
<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="get*"
                   read-only="true"
                   rollback-for="NoProductInStockException"/>
        <tx:method name="*"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

Or with the *annotation*:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = NoProductInStockException.class)
```

Detailed documentation you can find in the official Spring documentation:
 [Introduction to Spring Framework transaction management](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html)

Hope that helps.